# Java - Need to initialize variable before Constructor calls super()

Tags: java, spring, constructor, abstract-class, super

**Note**: some of the code will be in spanish.

Hi. I made a good Exception model for my Spring Boot app, so that every personalized exception I throw creates a personalized response (int this case it's a class called `ErrorModel`), so then I can catch that exception in a `@RestControllerAdvice` with an `@ExceptionHandler`, and just return the `errorModel` that that particular exception created. What's particular about each `errorModel` that's created in the personalized exceptions are a `code` and a `description`.

```java
@Slf4j
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
  @ExceptionHandler(ClienteSinMorasException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  @ResponseBody
  public ErrorModel manejoDeClienteSinMoras(ClienteSinMorasException ex) {
      return ex.getErrorModel();
  }
}
```

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ErrorModel {
    private final String codigo;
    private final String descripcion;
    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> errores; //don't take this into consideration
}
```

So, because each exception is and works the same, and the only diference is the `code` (`codigo`) and `description` (`descipcion`), I created this, and it worked fine:

```java
public abstract class IErrorException extends RuntimeException {
    @Getter
    private final ErrorModel errorModel;

    public abstract String getCodigo();

    public abstract String getDescripcion();

    public IErrorException() {
        super();
        this.errorModel = new ErrorModel(this.getCodigo(), this.getDescripcion(), null);
    }

    public IErrorException(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> errores) {
        super();
        this.errorModel = new ErrorModel(this.getCodigo(), this.getDescripcion(), errores);
    }

    public IErrorException(String errorKey, String errorValue) {
        super();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> errores = new ArrayList<>();
        errores.add(new HashMap<>(Map.of(errorKey, errorValue)));
        this.errorModel = new ErrorModel(this.getCodigo(), this.getDescripcion(), errores);
    }

}
```

```java
// One of the exceptions
@Getter
public class ClienteSinMorasException extends IErrorException {

    private final String codigo = "code";
    private final String descripcion = "desc";

    public ClienteSinMorasException() {
        super();
    }

    public ClienteSinMorasException(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> errores) {
        super(errores);
    }

    public ClienteSinMorasException(String errorKey, String errorValue) {
        super(errorKey, errorValue);
    }

}
```

This was perfect (except for those supers, but whatever), but recently, they asked me to change it so that the `code` and `description` are read from .yml properties, so that the values could be changed at runtime without needing to rerun the app. That simple change broke everything.

I came to understand that the only reason that that worked was because `final` fields of `explicit primitive` types "kinda already exist" when in the abstract class I do `this.getCodigo()` (in this example, this returns "code"). If it's not `final` nor is it of an `explicit primitive` type, this doesn't work, it loads everything AFTER the execution of the constructor, thus I end up creating a `new ErrorModel(null, null, null)`. Also, `super()` has to be the first thing in the constructor, so I can't quite initialize the variables correctly.

```java
// One of the exceptions
@Getter
public class ClienteSinMorasException extends IErrorException {

    private final String codigo = Yml.get("cod");
    private final String descripcion = Yml.get("desc");

    public ClienteSinMorasException() {
        super();
    }

    public ClienteSinMorasException(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> errores) {
        super(errores);
    }

    public ClienteSinMorasException(String errorKey, String errorValue) {
        super(errorKey, errorValue);
    }

}
```

This doesn't work, and honestly I don't know what to do.

Comment: Could you change it so that the `ErrorModel` is lazily created by its getter?

Comment: Two ideas. (1) If possible, place the two fields in the superclass (or in an intermediate class for those exceptions where it makes sense to have them) and initialize them through the `super` call: `super(Yml.get("cod"), Yml.get("desc"), errores);`, etc. (2) Assuming that `get` is a static method in the `Yml` class, would it help making the fields `codigo` and `description` static in the custom exception class (like `ClienteSinMorasException`) too?

Comment: As an aside, assuming you don’t need to modify the error model after it has been created, declare `private final List<Map<String, String>> errores;` and similar wherever it as passed as parameter. May also make a defensive copy in the constructor so any subsequent modifications the caller may make don’t harm you.

Comment: Under all circumstances calling overridable methods from a constructor is a bad and discouraged practice exactly because it easily leads to errors like the one you have. So you should change the design to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 2):

field initializers aren't run until later. However, those 2 fields you have do not appear to serve any function. You do not need them. At best, they exist as a somewhat crappy take on caching the values of your Yml reader. Crappy in the sense that every instance of an exception re-creates them, it'd be far more efficient, if caching is the point, to do so within the Yml class itself.

Hence, get rid of the fields entirely. Either they served no point at all, or the point was to serve as a cache (i.e. to avoid repeated hammering of the disk to re-read that YML file a lot). If it was cache - this was the wrong place for it, edit the code of `Yml` to add caching behaviour there. Either way, the proper take on this exception type would be:

```
public class ClienteSinMorasException extends IErrorException {

    @Override public String getCodigo() {
      return Yml.get("cod");
    }

    @Override public String getDescripcion() {
      return Yml.get("desc");
    }

    public ClienteSinMorasException() {
        super();
    }

    public ClienteSinMorasException(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> errores) {
        super(errores);
    }

    public ClienteSinMorasException(String errorKey, String errorValue) {
        super(errorKey, errorValue);
    }
}
```

This avoids the issue: There are no fields, so there are no field initializers, so you don't run into any issues in regards to initialization sequence problems.

Comment: The base class `IErrorException` has a field `errorModel` which is initialized by its constructor by calling the overridden getters. Are you saying the OP should also get rid of that?

Comment: @k314159 I didn't and I have no idea why you would think this answer suggests this.

Comment: You said "Hence, get rid of the fields entirely." But `errorModel` _is_ a field.

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I wanted! I got into a tricky situation, but this solution keeps the original idea while making it work, so I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

so I'm the one who originally posted the question. The above answer is what I used..... until I recently came to understand that all of this was stupid from my part. Here is my new answer.

So, basically, I was shooting myself in the foot. The reason is simple: ***I don't need to do all of this when initializing the class!!!*** I can just do it when I call `.getErrorModel()`, which is when I need it, not before. It's such an obvious oversight, it seems I was blinded by the `@Getter`, trying to use it and not code any sort of getter myself. This is the new solution.

```java
public abstract class IErrorException extends RuntimeException {

    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> errores = null;

    public abstract String getCodigo();

    public abstract String getDescripcion();

    public IErrorException() {
        super();
    }

    public IErrorException(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> errores) {
        super();
        this.errores = errores;
    }

    public IErrorException(String errorKey, String errorValue) {
        super();
        this.errores = new ArrayList<>();
        this.errores.add(new HashMap<>(Map.of(errorKey, errorValue)));
    }

    public ErrorModel getErrorModel() {
        return new ErrorModel(this.getCodigo(), this.getDescripcion(), this.errores);
    }

}
```

And then:

```java
public class ClienteSinMorasException extends IErrorException {

    public ClienteSinMorasException() {
        super();
    }

    public ClienteSinMorasException(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> errores) {
        super(errores);
    }

    public ClienteSinMorasException(String errorKey, String errorValue) {
        super(errorKey, errorValue);
    }

    @Override public String getCodigo() {
      return "Codigo";
    }

    @Override public String getDescripcion() {
      return "descripcion";
    }
}
```

I think this is the best solution so far as it doesn't play so close to the edge unnecesarily. Lesson learned.